# Any way to clean up my code for a simple console calculator?

Tags: c#, console-application

Is there any way for me to clean this code up for it to be more efficient? Also, could someone point me into the direction of making this app more advanced than what I have done?

As I am progressing with C# and starting to understand more about what certain things do I am lost as to how to implement my knowledge into actual code.

Any starting points for creating applications to help me remember how to and when to use certain code, for example: Encapsulation, interface polymorphism etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DotNetCalculator

{public class Calculator

    {
        // User Input1
        public int number1;

        // User Input2
        public int number2;

        // User Input3
        public int number3;

        //User Input4
        public char YesOrNo;

        // Input1 property
        public int Input1 { get
            {
                return number1;
            } set {
                number1 = value;
            }
        }
        // Input2 property
        public int Input2 { get
            {
                return number2;
            } set {
                number2 = value;
            }
        }
        // Input3 property
        public int Input3
        {
            get
            {
                return number3;
            }
            set { 
                number3 = value;
            }
        }
        // Input4 property
        public char Input4
        {
            get
            {
                return YesOrNo;
            }
            set
            {
                YesOrNo = value;
            }
        }
        //Addition
        public void Addition(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAddition of the 2 Numbers is " + (number1 + number2));
        }

        //Subtraction
        public void Subtraction(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subtraction of the 2 Numbers is: " + (number1 - number2));
        }

        //Division
        public void Division(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Division of the 2 Numbers is: " + (number1 / number2));
        }

        //Multiplication
        public void Multiplication(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Multiplication of the 2 Numbers is: " + (number1 * number2));
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator calc = new Calculator();
            //Start of the application
            Start:
            Console.WriteLine("\nCalculation of the 2 numbers using 4 different operations");

            //User input with the first number

            Console.Write("\nEnter The first number: ");
            calc.Input1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            //User input with the second number

            Console.Write("Enter the second number: ");
            calc.Input2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            //User input which is equal to 1 of the 4 math operations

            Console.Write("Press 1 for Addition, Press 2 for Subtraction, Press 3 for Division or Press 4 for Multiplication: ");
            calc.number3 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            // if the user input is 1 then call the addition operation

            if (calc.number3 == 1)
            {
                //call addition

                calc.Addition(calc.number1, calc.number2);
            }
            else
            // if the user input is 2 then call the subtraction operation
                if (calc.number3 == 2)
            {
                //call subtraction
                calc.Subtraction(calc.number1, calc.number2);
            }
            else
            // if the user input is 3 then call the division operation
                if (calc.number3 == 3)
            {
                //call division
                calc.Division(calc.number1, calc.number2);
            }
            else
            // if the user input is 4 then call the multiplication operation
                if (calc.number3 == 4)
            {
                //call multiplication 
                calc.Multiplication(calc.number1, calc.number2);
            }

            //User input for starting again or finishing the application
            Console.Write("\nWould you like to start again? Y or N: ");
            calc.YesOrNo = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            //if the user input is equal to Y then send them back to the start of the application
            if (calc.YesOrNo == 'Y')
            {
                goto Start;
            }
            else
            // if the user input is equal to N then send them to the end of the application
                if (calc.YesOrNo == 'N')
            {
                goto End;
            }

            //End of the application
            End:
            //Exit
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit!");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code works without bugs, but you want critique on how to make it better, this is not the right site to ask on; you should post this on [codereview.se].

Comment: Ok thank you, new to using this site. Sorry!

Comment: @MikeH Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Ok, thanks.  I thought I read on meta that "other" was the right action, but your link makes it clear it's not.  I probably just mis-remembered.

Comment: u can get rid of number1, number2 and use auto implemented properties

Comment: Try reusing variables, you should be able make the entire calculator with 2 user input variables and an output variable.

Answer (score 0):

My comments:

- In your `Calculator` class, you should not put variable that are not useful for the class like `number3`.
- No reason to have both a public variable and a property.
- No reason to use `goto` in a program like that. Prefer `while` loop.
- Find better name for your variables.
- You main function should be split in multiple small functions.
- Use `enum` for operations.
- Be consistent with your types. Given that the calculator accept 32 bit inputs, you should probably convert user input to 32 bit integers.
- Formatting could be improved
- And more...